Launch one single SBATCH script that changes the number of nodes
I need to test the scalability of a distributed algorithm, and when running tests on my cluster of choice, I would love to dynamically set up the number of nodes in a single script.
What I want to avoid is:

ask N nodes and then run a portion of the test with n<N nodes (I would lose compute hours)
have many different sbatch requests that overlaps
possibly do everything with a single SBATCH script

What I wanted to  submit a script like:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p <req_partition>       # Partition name
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:<no_gpu>      # No GPUs requested
#SBATCH -N 128                   # Number of nodes
#SBATCH -n 128                   # Total number of tasks
#SBATCH --time=06:00:00          # Time limit
#SBATCH --exclusive              # Exclusive access to nodes
#SBATCH --account=<account name> # Account name

/run_tests.sh 128                # run the test suite on 128 node

#SBATCH -N 64                    # Number of nodes
#SBATCH -n 64                    # Total number of tasks

/run_tests.sh 64                 # run the test suite on 64 node

#SBATCH -N 32                    # Number of nodes
#SBATCH -n 32                    # Total number of tasks

/run_tests.sh 32                 # run the test suite on 32 node

#SBATCH -N 16                    # Number of nodes
#SBATCH -n 16                    # Total number of tasks

/run_tests.sh 16                 # run the test suite on 16 node

Apart from the feasibility of a script like this, another concern is the fact that I don't know if reducing the number of nodes is blocking (i.e., can I expect that the next test run after some nodes are relinquished or, on the contrary, expect that the nodes are relinquished while I'm running the test, thus probably invalidating my test results).

note the low number of watchers on most of the tags you have used. You need to find a tag where there are a large number of users that understand #SBATCH (directives?) . Apparently most bash users don't have that experience. Good luck.

AFAIK, you cannot dynamically change the resource reservation; that would mess up with the scheduling SLURM is doing. You should go for your first option (asking for N and running for n<N) or second option (multiple scripts, each one with the desired resources for that execution).

You can use the scontrol command to shrink your allocation in terms of nodes. See the related question in the Slurm FAQ
For consistency, you should probably defined the number of tasks proportional to the number of nodes with --ntasks-per-node.
Your script would look like this (untested):
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p <req_partition>       # Partition name
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:<no_gpu>      # No GPUs requested
#SBATCH -N 128                   # Number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1                   # Number of tasks per node
#SBATCH --time=06:00:00          # Time limit
#SBATCH --exclusive              # Exclusive access to nodes
#SBATCH --account=<account name> # Account name

/run_tests.sh 128                # run the test suite on 128 node

scontrol update JobId=$SLURM_JOB_ID NumNodes=64
. slurm_job_${SLURM_JOB_ID}_resize.sh

/run_tests.sh 64                 # run the test suite on 64 node

scontrol update JobId=$SLURM_JOB_ID NumNodes=32
. slurm_job_${SLURM_JOB_ID}_resize.sh

/run_tests.sh 32                 # run the test suite on 32 node

scontrol update JobId=$SLURM_JOB_ID NumNodes=16
. slurm_job_${SLURM_JOB_ID}_resize.sh

/run_tests.sh 16                 # run the test suite on 16 node


Sorry, just for clarification, the . slurm_job_${SLURM_JOB_ID}_resize.sh would be a separate bash script I need to write with the /run_test.sh inside it or?

No, it will be created by the scontrol update ... command. Its purpose is to update the job environment with the new job characteristics.
